# How to limit or filter input in Mask TextBox in Windows application

Tags: c#, datetime, windows, maskedtextbox

**Update: Edited my question for better understanding I hope**

I set my `Mask TextBox` properties to shortdate `MM/DD/YYYY` or `00/00/0000` but it can accept month more than 12 and date more than 31. How can I filter month only to 12 and date only to 31?

Comment: Can you include your code in the question?

Comment: @Sam there's no code it in the properties

Comment: @Sam Under properties of Mask Textbox there's `Mask`

Comment: *Strongly* consider using a DateTimePicker control instead. It is designed explicitly for this purpose, and offers a richer user interface without sacrificing any power of the MaskedTextBox.

Comment: @CodyGray I know that but my end users didn't like the UI of the DateTimePicker on touch screen monitor since they don't want to scroll the year and date everytime the use it.

Comment: @CodyGray so I tried a `Mask TextBox` with number buttons similar to the numpad but only numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
^([012]\d|30|31)/(0\d|10|11|12)/\d{4}$
```

use above regular expression in your overridden control.

Comment: Can you specify on how to do that? Where should I put it?

Comment: in properties window of textbox, there will be masked textbox regular expression property. Put it there.

Comment: I can't find it in the Mask Textbox's properties.

Comment: you must use maskedtextbok http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: By the way, I'm not using a regular textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a work around for this problem so here it is. Mine is inputting the user's birthdate month cannot be higher than 12 and year must be less than today's year (haven't solved on how to accept current year.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000";
        maskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = typeof(System.DateTime);
        maskedTextBox1.TypeValidationCompleted += new TypeValidationEventHandler(maskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted);


    }

    void maskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsValidInput)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The data you supplied must be a valid date in the format mm/dd/yyyy.");
        }
        else
        {

            DateTime userDate = (DateTime)e.ReturnValue;
            if (userDate >= DateTime.Now)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("The date in this field must be less or equal than today's date.");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```